# Angular2, BREAKING CHANGES - Separation in different modules

Tags: angular, systemjs

I tried to pass "5 MIN QUICKSTART" tutorial from the angular site but faced some difficulties that the tutorial is for `2.0.0-alpha.44` but the latest version is `2.0.0-alpha.53` and there are some breaking changes, as i understood is that now you have to import the modules in a different way: not `from 'angular2/angular2'` but i.e. `from 'angular2/core'`.

Therefore it produces some problems with the modules loading. As i understood i need to correct SystemJS somehow to search modules in `node_modules` folder. The question is: what am i to do to make this tutorial work for the latest on the current moment angular 2 version?

Comment: *Therefore it produces some problems with the modules loading*, can we know what problems are those?

Comment: @EricMartinez Earlier all the modules were taken from the single file which was included in script tag, but now it doesn't work because now i have to include modules separately and System.js tries to load them but they are placed in node_modules directory

Comment: 1. you just take care of all imports are from correct destination i.e for example angular2/core....etc 2. and try to insert all js files in the index.html in the order to avoid errors i have found best repo here https://github.com/pkozlowski-opensource/ng2-play/blob/master/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you didn't specify any problem, but let me shorten it for you,
Here is the [changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) for angular2.

use this config for alpha53,

```
<script>
System.config({
  packages: {
    'app': {defaultExtension: 'js'}
  }
});
 System.import('app/app');
</script>
```

and import like this

```
import { provide, component } from 'angular2/core';
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser' ;
```

if you still can't get it work, try to use a starter kit instead eventually you will get to know how everything works.

[angular2-webpack-starter](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/)

[NG6-starter](https://github.com/AngularClass/NG6-starter)

[angular2-seed](https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed)

Comment: you can also use  insted `system.config({defaultJSExtensions: true});` . this also work same.